# Import TestNG results from Jenkins to ALM

Tags: java, testng, quality-center, jenkins, hp-alm-12.01

I have Jenkins on localhost, configured test project, which is generating passed test:

```
    @Test
    public void aFastTest() {
        System.out.println("---- ---- ----");
        Assert.assertTrue(true, "Test is true");
    }
```

Console output is OK in Jenkins:

```
Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

For import to ALM I'm using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HP+Application+Automation+Tools

In Jenkins Job configuration I have in Post-build Actions - Upload test result to ALM, set:

```
Testing result file: **/testng-results.xml
```

And finally my problem - in the end of Jenkins console log is:

```
INFO: 'Upload test result to ALM' Post Build Step is being invoked.
INFO: No Test Report found.
INFO: 'Upload test result to ALM' Completed.
```

I thought, the path to testing result file is wrong, so I copied it everywhere, in testng-results.xml is valid result, compared to examples on net...Anyone know why there is **No Test Report found**?

Answer (score 0):

HP Automation jenkins plugin is searching for testng-results.xml inside bilds/buildid folder. So write below shell script and give  Testing result file as  `**/testng-results.xml` to fix this issue.

**Execute Shell Command:**

```
cp path_of_testng_resuls/testng_results.xml .jenkins/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/$BUILD_ID
```